# How can I decorate desktop-windows from commandline (red frame?, linusmint-cinnamon)

Tags: shell-script, window-decorations

I am "streaming" some of my desktop-windows to a remote host via `xwininfo` and `x11vnc -id $WINID`, which is already working.

Now I'd like to mark the windows, which I am streaming to the remote host, on the server-side.

How can I decorate these streamed windows (draw a red frame around them?), where I started `x11vnc`?

Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
WINID=$(xwininfo |awk '/Window id:/ {print $4}')
x11vnc -id $WINID
draw_red_frame $WINID

# and later on
draw_red_frame $WINID delete
```